# react-router generatePath with query parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react-router's built in function `generatePath` to generate a URL. The issue is that as far as I understand this function just returns the path and doesn't provide a mechanism for us to know which fields were added in the path and which were not.

For example, for the following code

```
generatePath('/user/:id', {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
})
```

the function returns `/user/1` which is correct, but there is no way for us to know that only `id` was inserted into the path and `name` needs to be passed as query parameters. 
In my application both the path template and the `params` object are dynamic and I need to add the extra fields in `params` as the query parameters.
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: It matches pattern provided as first argument in your case it happens to be `/user/:id` thus `name` is ignored. If you intend to have `name` as query param try `/user/:id?:name` not sure if that's the right pattern for query string though

Comment: @rikin But that would mean that I need to know that name should go into the query parameters in advance. The second parameter to `generatePath` is not known in advance. It is created on the run time based on user input

Comment: You can use router `state`  In that case, is that an option or you are relying on something else that is responsible for setting query parameter. Either way you dont need to declare query param in your route path rather you can just read from the location object and see if it has value in it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone checking now, I ended up using the `path-to-regexp` library which is the one used internally by react-router to generate the URL. The code looks something like this

```
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
import qs from 'qs';

const compiledCache = {};
export default function generatePathWithQueryParams(rawPath, params) {
    let toPath;
    if (compiledCache[rawPath]) {
        toPath = compiledCache[rawPath];
    } else {
        toPath = pathToRegexp.compile(rawPath);
        compiledCache[rawPath] = toPath;
    }
    const queryParams = { ...params };
    const path = toPath(params, {
        encode: (value, token) => {
            delete queryParams[token.name];
            return encodeURI(value);
        },
    });
    const queryString = qs.stringify(queryParams);
    if (queryString) {
        return `${path}?${queryString}`;
    }
    return path;
};
```